# Firebase Login: User can login with wrong credentials

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am finding that the user can log in with the wrong credentials. How would I fix this?

```
onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            setState(() => loading = true);
            dynamic result = await _auth
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context, Strings.userInfoPath));
            if (result == null) {
              setState(() {
                loading = false;
                error = Strings.couldNotLogInCred;
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, you're pushing the new screen without first checking the validity of the credentials, follows a possible solution:

```
onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            setState(() => loading = true);
            dynamic result = await _auth
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            if (result == null) {
              setState(() {
                loading = false;
                error = Strings.couldNotLogInCred;
              });
              return;
            }
            await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context, Strings.userInfoPath);
          }
}
```

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks a lot, it's fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: psw)
      .then((result) {
    //If sign in, this block works
  }).catchError((e) {
    //this block works if there is an error
  });
```